# Adding n rows each time and save the result in new data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

[image]

I have the above data frame I want the result to be like below where we are adding 2-2 rows and saving the result in new data frame which contains categorical column also. how to do it in pandas?

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)  instead take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make helping you easier.

Comment: r = df.groupby(df.index // 2).sum() I  tried this but I am not getting categorical variable which I want to retain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first build an auxiliary Series with same index as `df` and alterning values 0 and 1:

```
x = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)
x[x.index % 2 == 0] = 1
```

You can then use it to group df rows by pairs:

```
resul = df.groupby(['item', x.cumsum()]).sum().reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It should give the expected result (I cannot show since I could not copy the data sample)